# How to change elements to default value after button click?

Tags: javascript, html

After the timer ends and I hit the End Session button, I want it to display the start button and have it look like it does from the beginning. I've got the first part where I get the start button to display, but the `counter` is still there. What is the best way to do this?

```js
var startButton = document.getElementById("start");
var startSound = document.getElementById("audio"); 
var timerSound = document.getElementById("timer");
var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
var pausePlay = document.getElementsByClassName("pausePlay");
var pauseButton = document.getElementById("pause");
var playButton = document.getElementById('play');
var middleButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("middleButtons");
var fiveMin = document.getElementById("fiveMin");
var end = document.getElementById("endSess");
var redo = document.getElementById("redo");


function playAudio(){
    startSound.play();
}

// Start button will disappear after click and countDown method will begin
function startTimer(){
    startButton.style.display="none"; 
    for (var i = 0; i < pausePlay.length; i++) {
        pausePlay[i].style.display = "block";
      }

    
    countDown(10);
}
// function play(){
   
// }

function countDown(minutes){
    var seconds = 60;
    var mins = minutes;
    function tick(){

        var current_minutes = mins - 1;
        seconds --;

        counter.innerHTML = current_minutes.toString() + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds);
        if(seconds > 0){
            timer = setTimeout(tick, 1);
        } else {
            if(mins > 1){
                countDown(mins - 1);
            }
            else if (mins && seconds === 0 ){
               timerSound.play();
               for (var i = 0; i < pausePlay.length; i++){
                pausePlay[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                options();
            }
        }
    }    
    tick();
  }
// Pause timer
  function pauseTimer(){
    clearInterval(timer);
    disable(pauseButton); enable(playButton);
  }
// Continue timer
function playTimer(){
   countDown();
}
 

// Display buttons after timer is finished  
  function options(){
    for(var i = 0; i < middleButtons.length; i++){
        middleButtons[i].style.display = "block";
    }
  }
// Add five minutes to Counter as countdown
  function fiveBreak (){
      countDown(5);
  }
// Restart counter to another 25 minutes
  function restartTimer(){
    countDown(10);
}

// Start from the beginning with the start timer
  function endSess(){
    for(var i = 0; i < middleButtons.length; i++){
        middleButtons[i].style.display = "none";
        counter.style.display = "none";
    }
     startButton.style.display = "";
  }

startButton.addEventListener('click', startTimer, playAudio);
pauseButton.addEventListener('click', pauseTimer, playAudio );
playButton.addEventListener('click', playTimer, playAudio );
fiveMin.addEventListener('click', fiveBreak );
end.addEventListener('click', endSess);
redo.addEventListener('click', restartTimer);
```

```css
body {

    background-image: url("imgs/path.jpeg")
}

a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: inherit !important;
}
.header {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 70px;
    font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
    font-size: 100px;
    
}
/* h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Shadows Into Light', cursive;

} */

#pom-header {
    font-size: 100px;
}

.container {
   display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
 

}


.buttons {
    display: flex;
    /* margin-top: 400px; */
    height: 500px;
    
    align-items: center;
}
.pausePlay {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 75px;
}

#start {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 500px;
    border-width: 5px;
    font-size: 50px;
    padding: 50px;
    outline:none;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

#pause, #play {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border-width: 5px;
    font-size: 5px;
    padding: 50px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    outline:none;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

#fiveMin, #endSess, #redo {
    margin-top: 40px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 90px;
    border-width: 5px;
    font-size: 1px;
    padding: 50px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    outline:none;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}


#pause:hover, #play:hover{
    background-color: #02798F;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    transition: all 0.20s ease;
}


#fiveMin:hover, #endSess:hover, #redo:hover{
    background-color: #02798F;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    transition: all 0.20s ease;
}
#start:hover{
 background-color: #02798F;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    transition: all 0.20s ease;
}

#counter {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    align-items:center;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 100px;
    padding-top: 120px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Pomodoro App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gloria+Hallelujah" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">
    

</head>
<body>

        <div class="header">   
            
                <h1 id="pom-header"><a href="https://francescocirillo.com/pages/pomodoro-technique">Pomodoro</a> App</h1>
        </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="buttons">
                <button id ="start" type="button" onclick="playAudio()">Start</button>
                <audio id="audio">
                    <source src="clicksound.wav" type="audio/ogg "> 
                </audio>
                <audio id="timer">
                    <source src="gong.mp3" type="audio/ogg "> 
                </audio>
        </div>

        <div id="middle">
            <div id="counter"></div>
            <div class="pausePlay" style="display: none">
              <div class="row mr-3">
                <button id="pause">
                    <i class="fas fa-pause" style="font-size: 40px"></i>
                  <!-- <i class="fas fa-pause" style="font-size: 40px"></i> -->
                </button>
                <button id="play" onclick="playAudio()">
                   <i class="fas fa-play" style="font-size: 40px"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="middleButtons" style="display: none">
              <div class="row mr-3">
                <button id="fiveMin" onclick="playAudio()">
                  <h1>5 Min Break</h1>
                </button>
                <button id="redo" onclick="playAudio()">
                  <h1>Restart</h1>
                <button id="endSess" onclick="playAudio()">
                  <h1>End Session</h1>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


        
    
    
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please do not post your code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time making your question meaningless. Always include your code, right here in your question. Just click the code snippet button on the edit toolbar to do so as I've done for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for, but try just resetting `display` of `counter` each time you press the start button, i.e. at the beginning of `startTimer` function:

```js
// Start button will disappear after click and countDown method will begin
function startTimer(){
    startButton.style.display="none"; 
    counter.style.display = "";  // <----------------------HERE
    for (var i = 0; i < pausePlay.length; i++) {
        pausePlay[i].style.display = "block";
      }


    countDown(10);
}
```